# Python f-string not formatting whitespace for object property

Tags: python, string-formatting

I have an object with a property called `key` and using `f-string` I want to format it to have `8` whitespaces to the left of the string.

Here is an example:

```py
object = {}

object['key'] = 'JIRA-123'

print(f"{object['key']:>8} should be 8 spaces to the right.")
print(f"{'But':>8} it isn't 8 spaces to the right.")
```

When this is run, this is the output:

```
JIRA-123 should be 8 spaces to the right.
     But it isn't 8 spaces to the right.
```

When the output I'm expecting is:

```
     JIRA-123 should be 8 spaces to the right.
     But it isn't 8 spaces to the right.
```

You can try it out [here](https://trinket.io/python3/199c5df299).

Comment: You are confused about the formatting.  What you are asking for is just spaces, not a field width.

Comment: `:>8` means that it will be in a field that's 8 characters wide. If the value is shorter than that, spaces will be added on the left.

Comment: When using align, you say "in a space of n characters, I want my string of k characters to be aligned to the left/center/right". If n and k are equals, you got a "left" aligned string. Try add " "*8 before your f string (not aligned) and it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments by @Stephen Rauch you are confused with formatting.
Here is the explanation Hope you will find helpful.

```
>>> len('But')
>>> 3
>>> f"{'But':>8}" # output will be 8 characters wide 
>>> '     But'    # Since len of But is 3 left 5 length will be filled out by whitespaces in left
>>> object['key'] = 'JIRA-123'
>>> len(object['key'])
>>> 8
>>> f"{object['key']:>8}" # output will be 8 characters wide 
>>> 'JIRA-123'            # since length is already of 8 no whitespaces in left
```